# Fill NA values (for factor valued columns) with values according to distribution of the factors?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a data frame df with multiple factor columns, say column A with factors a,b,c, column B with factors m, f and so on.

Each of these columns have NA's.

1. How can I fill NA's with a, b, c and m, f according to their
   distribution in the column (for example if I have 50% males and 50%
   females (for simplicity) I will fill my NA's 50% as males, 50% as females)?
2. Is it a good technique if I have around 550 observations of data and 41 
   columns?

   - Next step will be to resample it to make the data set bigger and apply ML on the data set - please tell me which function will enlarge this data set to be 10000 observations or more?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt that's a good idea but you can use argument `prob` of `sample`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Why not? Any suggestion?

Comment: Because `NA` values are part of the data, there are ways in `R` to get rid of them on a case by case basis. For instance, in some functions you can set `na.rm = TRUE` or `na.omit` and `na.exclude`. But leave the original data as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code (please see below a couple of comments) (I created a small data frame to give you a concrete example)

```
A_ <- c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 60), rep("c", 30), rep(NA, 200))
A <- data.frame(A_)
names(A) <- c("A")

b <- sample(c("a","b","c"), size = 200, prob = c(10,60,30)/100,replace = TRUE)
A[is.na(A)] <- b
```

And you can check with

```
table(A)
```

Now you should be careful in changing the NA values. First of all I would check why you have NA. Maybe there is a reason why the information is not there. Changing the NA with values from a distribution, you automatically assume that the missing data follows the same distribution. Is really so? 550 observations are really not that many to talk about distribution. Maybe you need to simply ignore the records with NA?

Regarding your second question you cannot simply generate new data from your existing one. In some cases (see images for example, where you can tilt them, shift them and so on) you can "augment" your data set. With small data set as the one you describe I would not do it. 
It all depends on the kind of data you have. But my first impression is that in your cases, with 41 factors and many NA, you cannot simply augment your data.

Possibly knowing a bit more about your dataset could help us in giving you a more precise help.

Comment: We have a clinical experiment and 550 observations. I need to understand and predict if the medicine actually helps the patient. If a new one comes, based on the features and observations, will one benefit and respond to the medicine or not?